How to get the radio button value with two div in single element
i am new to the development. i have two div sections

Main Course
Main Gravy

i want to select Jeera Rice and Vegetable Kurma but in my code i am not able to select. i am able to select only one.


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightcyan;">
    <!-- Main Title like Min course,Gravy -->
    <h4 class="p-3 m-0 bg-light w-100" style="color:red">Main Course </h4>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control buffetCategory" value="Main Course">
    <!-- needs to take value from here-->
    <div class="col-md-12 px-0 border-top">
      <div class="d-flex gap-2 p-3 border-bottom gold-members">
        <input type="radio" name="buffetSelection" class="form-check-input buffetSelection" value="1">
        <div>
          <h5 class="mb-1">Biryani Rice</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 px-0 border-top">
      <div class="d-flex gap-2 p-3 border-bottom gold-members">
        <input type="radio" name="buffetSelection" class="form-check-input buffetSelection" value="2">
        <div>
          <h5 class="mb-1">Jeera Rice</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightcyan;">
    <!-- Main Title like Min course,Gravy -->
    <h4 class="p-3 m-0 bg-light w-100" style="color:red">Main Gravy </h4>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control buffetCategory" value="Main Gravy">
    <!-- needs to take value from here-->
    <div class="col-md-12 px-0 border-top">
      <div class="d-flex gap-2 p-3 border-bottom gold-members">
        <input type="radio" name="buffetSelection" class="form-check-input buffetSelection" value="6">
        <div>
          <h5 class="mb-1">Vegetable Dalcha</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 px-0 border-top">
      <div class="d-flex gap-2 p-3 border-bottom gold-members">
        <input type="radio" name="buffetSelection" class="form-check-input buffetSelection" value="7">
        <div>
          <h5 class="mb-1">Vegetable Kurma</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 px-0 border-top">
      <div class="d-flex gap-2 p-3 border-bottom gold-members">
        <input type="radio" name="buffetSelection" class="form-check-input buffetSelection" value="8">
        <div>
          <h5 class="mb-1">Vegetable Dalcha</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-theme text-white fw-bold w-100" onclick="get_buffetDetails()">PROCEED</button>

<script>
  function get_buffetDetails() {
    var selectedbuffet = $('input[name=buffetSelection].buffetSelection:checked').val();

    console.log(selectedbuffet);
  }
</script>



Expected output
// Output: [ [ 'Main course', 2 ], [ 'Main Gravy', 7 ]


There's very likely to be a duplicate question I haven't found yet, but... If you want to create two distinct groups of radio buttons each with their own selections then you have to give them different name values.  For any given name value only one radio button of that name can be selected.

@david can you please share your code, so will pick up from here

Radio buttons with the same name value only allow one selection.  This is by design.  If you want different groups of radio buttons, give a different name to each group.  For example:


<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightcyan;">
      <!-- Main Title like Min course,Gravy -->
      <h4 class="p-3 m-0 bg-light w-100" style="color:red">Main Course </h4>
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control buffetCategory" value="Main Course"> <!-- needs to take value from here-->
      <div class="col-md-12 px-0 border-top">
         <div class="d-flex gap-2 p-3 border-bottom gold-members">
            <input type="radio" name="mainCourseSelection" class="form-check-input buffetSelection" value="1">
            <div>
               <h5 class="mb-1">Biryani Rice</h5>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 px-0 border-top">  
         <div class="d-flex gap-2 p-3 border-bottom gold-members">
            <input type="radio" name="mainCourseSelection" class="form-check-input buffetSelection" value="2">
            <div>
               <h5 class="mb-1">Jeera Rice</h5>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightcyan;">
      <!-- Main Title like Min course,Gravy -->
      <h4 class="p-3 m-0 bg-light w-100" style="color:red">Main Gravy </h4>
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control buffetCategory" value="Main Gravy"> <!-- needs to take value from here-->
      <div class="col-md-12 px-0 border-top">
         <div class="d-flex gap-2 p-3 border-bottom gold-members">
            <input type="radio" name="mainGravySelection" class="form-check-input buffetSelection" value="6">
            <div>
               <h5 class="mb-1">Vegetable Dalcha</h5>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 px-0 border-top">
         <div class="d-flex gap-2 p-3 border-bottom gold-members">
            <input type="radio" name="mainGravySelection" class="form-check-input buffetSelection" value="7">
            <div>
               <h5 class="mb-1">Vegetable Kurma</h5>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 px-0 border-top">
         <div class="d-flex gap-2 p-3 border-bottom gold-members">
            <input type="radio" name="mainGravySelection" class="form-check-input buffetSelection" value="8">
            <div>
               <h5 class="mb-1">Vegetable Dalcha</h5>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>



Notice that the first "group" now uses name="mainCourseSelection" and the second "group" now uses name="mainGravySelection" so they are different groups of radio buttons.
Any selectors you use for JavaScript or CSS would need to change accordingly, and whatever logic processes the result of this form would need to change accordingly.

Yes got it. when i am clicking PROCEED button, i need to get the selected radio button values please check my Expected output and please share your code

@Divya: What code have you written to produce your “expected output”?  That’s a different issue than what you asked about in the question above.  Now that the original problem has been solved, you are encouraged to continue attempting to write your code.  If you encounter another specific problem, you can ask another question focusing on that specific problem.  Getting stuck on one thing doesn’t mean this community is going to finish your project for you.
